# Why do we use an exponential Martingale for the stopping time of a BIASED random walk?

Tags: martingales, random-walk, stopping-times

The following is a passage from the lecture notes:

> Let a simple random move to the right with probability $p$ and to the
>   left with probability $q = 1 − p$. We want the probability that it
>   hits level $b$ before it hits level $c$, started at $x$, $b <x< c$.
>   Let $τ$ be the stopping time of random walk hitting $b$ or $c$. Then,
>   Stopping the exponential martingale $M_n = (\frac{q}{p})^{X_n}$ we
>   have $\mathbb{E}(\frac{q}{p})^{X_τ} = (\frac{q}{p})^x \dots$

I do not understand why they take an exponential martingale.

Comment: Well, why not? What else would you suggest/expect...?

Comment: Why not $M_n = X_n - \mu n$ ?

Comment: $M_n := X_n - \mu n$ has the disadvantage that we need to know the mean $\mathbb{E}(\tau)$ (because, by the optional stopping theorem, $\mathbb{E}X_{\tau} = \mu \mathbb{E}(\tau)$).

Comment: but can't we classify the mean in terms of $p$ and $q$ ?

Comment: Yeah, sure. But how to do that? The exponential martingale allows you to calculate the probability that the random walk hits $b$ before $c$. *Knowing* this probability, you can use the martingale $(X_n-n \mu)_n$ to calculate $\mathbb{E}(\tau)$.